# How to install Ubuntu to a Lenovo R61 that has Windows installed but not activated?

Tags: system-installation

I have my old lenovo R61 ThinkPad with a new harddrive and Windows xp installed but not activated since my windows product key expired after graduation or somthing like that.

I would like to start using ubuntu but I can not figure out how to install ubuntu onto my thinkpad without a currently opperating os. I already downloaded Ubuntu 12.10 to a USB from my desktop.

Now what? 
Please help! It will save me a great deal of frustration.

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to just download the ubuntu iso to a usbflashdrive.  Also you have to use *unetbootin* , *lili*, or another live usb creator to make a live usbflashdrive. Afterwards you can install ubuntu by booting your computer from the flashdrive. (You may have to change the bootorder in your bios, as long as the usbflashdrive boots before the hdd, you'll be ok.)

If you are planning to install ubuntu and remove windows choose use entire disk during the ubuntu installation, windows will be removed.

If your machine can't boot from usb burn the ubuntu iso onto a dvd and follow the above instructions. (Boot dvd before hdd.)

If you would like to dualboot windows and ubuntu follow these instructions on the ubuntu documentation site: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot. Make sure, before you start the dual boot install, to make space for the ubuntu install from within windows (disk manager).

*lili*:  http://www.linuxliveusb.com/ 
*unetbootin*:  google it because I'm not allowed to place more than two hyperlinks.

Comment: By the way I recommend installing ubuntu 12.04 instead of ubuntu 12.10. Ubuntu 12.04 is an lts which means it is more stable and supported for five years. (lts = long term support).